# Storing recursive results backwards

Tags: python, class, recursion

I am working on this problem that was asked by Google (not to me):

> Given the root to a binary tree, implement serialize(root), which
> serializes the tree into a string, and deserialize(s), which
> deserializes the string back into the tree.

This is what I have so far, but I cannot seem to make the function serialize store the results (from bottom of the tree and up) into a string. So I'm able to print the results, just not store it...

```
class Tree:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.ser_str = None

    def insert(self, data):
        if self.data:
            if data < self.data:
                if self.left is None:
                    self.left = Tree(data)
                else:
                    self.left.insert(data)
            elif data >= self.data:
                if self.right is None:
                    self.right = Tree(data)
                else:
                    self.right.insert(data)
        else:
            self.data = data

    def serialize(self):
        if self.left:
            self.left.serialize()
        print(self.data)
        if self.right:
            self.right.serialize()

root = Tree(23)
root.insert(10);root.insert(124);root.insert(101);root.insert(1);root.insert(40)
print("here comes the sun")
test = root.serialize()
```

Comment: You should "return" instead of "print" and you should concatenate the results of the subcalls to "serialize" with the data of the current node to a string to return it.

Comment: Should you come up with a format for the string yourself, or is it given? I don't think your format would allow for a unambiguous deserialization.

Comment: @tobias_k: Your guess is as good as mine =) All I have is that question =) In my head I was thinking a string str(), but I dunno...

Comment: @MichaelButscher: that sounds fantastic, I just can't wrap my head around how to do that

Comment: What is the problem? How to return a value from a function, how to assign a returned value to a variable (you do this already in the code), how to concatenate strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in comments, the problem with your method is that you just print the data, but never join it to a string and return it. However, that format would also not allow for an unambiguous deserialization of the tree.

If you do not want to use libraries like `json`, which make this trivial, you could resort to an easily parseable format like [Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation), where `a + b` is written as `+ a b`. In the tree case, the `data` corresponds to the operator and the `left` and `right` branch to the operands.

```
def serialize(t):
    if t is None:
        return "-"
    else:
        return f"{t.data} {serialize(t.left)} {serialize(t.right)}"
    
def deserialize(s):
    if isinstance(s, str): s = iter(s.split())
    # using an iterator of chunks makes this easier
    d = next(s)
    if d == "-":
        return None
    else:
        return Tree(d, deserialize(s), deserialize(s))
```

(Note that I made those functions, not methods, and added a few optional parameters to the `Tree` constructor to make the code simpler.)

When testing with your tree, this serialized the tree to `23 10 1 - - - 124 101 40 - - - -`. (I then deserialized the tree and serialized it again and got the same format, so deserialization should work, too.) You can add parens to better see the tree structure in the string: `(23 (10 (1 - -) -) (124 (101 (40 - -) -) -))`, but the format is unambiguous even without parens.

This basically corresponds to a simple pre-order traversal of the tree, whereas you are doing an in-order traversal, which, like infix-notation `a + b`, is not unambiguous without parentheses. In-order traversal returns the elements in sorted order, which is nice for some uses, but not here, as it means that differently structured trees holding the same element will serialize to the same sorted list. You *could*, of course, just add parens, but that will make parsing/deserialization much harder. With parens and in-order, your tree would be `(((- 1 -) 10 -) 23 (((- 40 -) 101 -) 124 -))`.

(Note: Even if the serialization is ambiguous, you could recreate a binary tree from that, but the form of that tree will be different; in particular, it will be a degenerate binary tree if you just insert the elements in sorted order, as they come out of in your in-order-traversal.)

Comment: Thank you so much! :) it is always so simple and elegant when you see it done right!

Comment: what was the two arguments you added to the Tree class? I assume it is left and right node, but then I'm curious how left is not always equal to right since arguments are always the same =)

Comment: @Helen Exactly, the left and right node so I can do that bit in one line instead of four. They are not the same because the argument to `deserialize`, `s`, is an iterator of the tokens in the serialization, and the state of that iterator will be different after the serialization of the `left` child.

Comment: AH, of course! Now I understand, that is brilliant! Thanks again =)